# How to make an alarm application fire when alarm has matured?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am building an alarm application in Android Java using the C# Xamarin framework. I have done almost everything according to the Android Java play book, but the Alarm Manager Service does not fire my alarm for some reason.

I have a TimePicker and DatePicker objects in my application, I use the TimePicker to read the time and minute set by the user and the the DatePicker to read the day of the week the user intends to be reminded of a certain event. When I do a check on a sample time, I have set as the trigger time, then everything seems to be okay, but there is this parameter of `AlarmManager.Set(..,PendingIntent pIntent)`. I believe the object specifies the operation that needs to be performed when the Alarm has matured. Could that have something to do with why the application does not do anything when the time has matured?

I have declared all the required permissions in my manifest file as follows.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
```

I then access a calendar instance and ask use my timepicker and datepicker objects to set it. I did this, because I was going to need the calendar time in milliseconds as a parameter in the `AlarmManager.Set()` call.

```
//adjust the time in the the calendar variable using the minute and hour from the timepicker
Calendar calendar= Calendar.Instance;
//make sure the instance fields are manipulated hierarchically    
          calendar.Set(mycalendar.Year,mycalendar.Month,mycalendar.DayOfMonth,timepicker.Hour,timepicker.Minute);
//use the alarm manager to set a new alarm with a pending Intent object
         _alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtimeWakeup,calendar.TimeInMillis,alarmoperation);
//this pending intent specifies the kind of operation that will happen when 
//the alarm goes live
```

This is the PendingIntent that gets called when the alarm matures

```
 PendingIntent alarmoperation = CreatePendingResult(908, new Intent(), PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
```

How do I program a pending intent to fire an alarm if that is what is causing the application not to fire? Is it because I used an empty intent as a constructor parameter when I created the pending intent?

Comment: Not exactly an Xamarin Coder, but according  to what you  say, I can provide you an  answer but  it will be Andro-Java.  If not possible ok:)

Comment: The answer is welcome, I can convert the source code to C# Xamarin very easily

Comment: Sorry @TechGeek, the problem is, my answer is also not working....

Comment: So sorry....thnx

Comment: FYI - use SetRepeating(), not set() as if you use set() your app must be active until set() call

Comment: Source: ANDROID DOCS

Answer (score -1):

I might be sure that this works:)
Open a Util class, i called it Scheduler, it can schedule notification task or a alarm task :)You choose alarm, since my app needs both :D

```
/**
 * Set the context to use in AlarmManager/Database. They all require {@linkplain Context}
 * for many different purposes
 * <p>
 *     For this very reason, Scheduler requires you to provide context. Also, Util class {@link
 *     com.functionality.app.homepage.LifeStyleUtils} has most of its functions requiring {@link
 *     Context}.
 * </p>
 * @param ctx The context to use in issue raising in LifeStyleUitls,  e.t.c.
 */
public Scheduler(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

public int scheduleNotification(LocalDateTime time, Intent intent, int code) {
    try {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, time.getMinute());
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, time.getHour());
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, time.getMonthValue());

        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, time.getYear());
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, time.getDayOfMonth());

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx,
                code, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmService.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),  1000* 60 * 5,
                pendingIntent);

        return SUCCESS;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
}
/**
 * Schedule a task outside the life cycle of app.
 *
 * @param time The time to set the task.
 * @param intent The intent to use, including the Receiver class.
 * @return failure or sucess.
 */
public int scheduleTask(LocalDateTime time, Intent intent, int code) {
    try {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, time.getMinute());
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, time.getHour());
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, time.getMonthValue());

        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, time.getYear());
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, time.getDayOfMonth());

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx,
                code, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmService.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),  1000* 60 * 5,
                pendingIntent);

        return SUCCESS;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
}
public static PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Intent intent, Context context) {
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
}
public void cancelAlarm(PendingIntent pendingIntent) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager= (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
public void cancelNotification(PendingIntent pendingIntent) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager= (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
```

}

Note: use the function "scheduleTask" not "scheduleNotification". Also, If you need reciever code, just comment, i'll send you, i dont wanna send since it will expose my idea, not sending notification since you need alarm. Also, R.raw file is my mp3 samusng galaxy on horizon recording, cant send you that.

Comment: Im hoping it solves your question

Comment: Convert it to Xamanrin first too.